# jQuery - live() not working with next() from appended div

Tags: jquery, append, jquery-selectors

The purpose of this element is to have a collapsible navigation system based entirely from a simple unordered list.  By default all nested lists will be hidden, and .toggle divs (buttons) attached to li items that contain a nested list.  These .toggle divs should then hide/show the nested list as well as apply a class to the toggle button.

I've tested this code by manually inserting the .toggle div (location noted with [toggle div]), and everything works perfectly.  When it's added through append() though, nothing seems to work.  Does anyone know what might be causing this problem?  Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">nav item</a>[toggle div]
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">nav item</a>[toggle div]
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">nav item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">nav item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">nav item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">nav item</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">nav item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">nav item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">nav item</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
$("#nav ul li").has("ul").append("<div class='toggle'></div>");
$(".toggle").live("click", function() {
    if($(this).next().is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).next().show();
        $(this).addClass("toggled");
    } else {
        $(this).next().hide();
        $(this).removeClass("toggled");
    }
});
});
```

Comment: What element has the id `#nav`? Also, you are appending the `toggle` div to the end of the `li`.

Comment: Sorry about that - just included the #nav div that's wrapping the unordered list.  Figured it out too!  I needed to switch the .next() to .prev() since it's not being appended where I manually placed it - a stupid oversight.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#nav li > ul").before('<div class="toggle"></div>');
```

If will select all `<ul>` elements which are directly nested in `<li>` elements, and adds the `<div>` in front of each of them.

Have a look at the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xXRSZ/1/

Comment: That's a perfect example of what I was trying to do.  It seems like this method will work with the original code, and is definitely a clean alternative to the append/prev changes I made.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is prepend the toggle div, not append it.

Update your code to use the `prepend` function:

```
$("#nav ul li").has("ul").prepend("<div class='toggle'>[toggle div]</div>");
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/uYBYQ/)

Comment: I think the poster wants to toggle the `<ul>`, not the anchor. Just put some CSS on and give some left margin to the `<li>`s to see what's wrong.